# How to configure github etc for Azure via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

Is it possible to configure a source control repository to deploy code to an Azure Web App slot via Powershell. (or even just the primary site)

Ideally for v2 / ARM but I'm willing to consider anything at the moment!

I have looked through the commands available in AzureRM.Websites module and there doesn't appear to be anything.

P.S. I know this is possible via template, I am currently looking for pure Powershell commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the 'low level' ARM CmdLets. e.g. for the main site:

```
$props = @{
    RepoUrl = $repoUrl
    Branch = "master"
}

New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/SourceControls -Name $SiteName/Web -PropertyObject $props -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

And for a slot (using same `$props`):

```
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/sourcecontrols -Name $SiteName/$SlotName/Web -PropertyObject $props -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

See also sample helper method [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/1004bf0e3d641b95b1bc94edaf4b74fc002c3910/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L177-L187). That one sets `IsManualIntegration = true`, which is for repos you don't own, and requires a manual sync. For continuous deployment, leave `IsManualIntegration` out.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (well, this and @ŁukaszKałużny 's answer) but since you answered first - albeit by a few minutes!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **New-AzureRmResource** command.

```
$webappname = "name of your webapp"
$RepoUrl = "https://github.com/davidebbo-test/Mvc52Application.git"
$branch = "master"
$location = "location of your webapp "
$resourceGroupName = "name of resource group with your webapp"
New-AzureRmResource -Location $location -Properties @{"RepoUrl"="$RepoUrl";"branch"="$branch";"IsManualIntegration"="true"} -ResourceName $webappname -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols/web -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ApiVersion 2015-08-01-preview
```